# .on click function happening before dynamic class is clicked jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

So I have some code where a class(elink) when clicked changes to a different class(playing), and then when .playing gets clicked it should change classes again to .pause, but my problem is when I click the .elink it adds both .playing and .pause at the same time.

So I tried using an alert when you click .playing, but it triggers when you click .elink.  I'm very confused as to why this would be happening. Heres the jquery I'm using

```
player();
function player() {
  $(".elink").click(function(e) {
    $(".playing").addClass("elink").removeClass("playing");
    $(this).removeClass("elink").addClass("playing");
  });
}

$('body').on("click", ".playing", function(){
  $(this).addClass("paused")
});
```

Comment: Where do you expect `$(this)` to point in the function `player` ? this will not work the way set it up

Comment: Sorry accidently deleted that part of the code its right now

Comment: click events are bound to elements, not classes. removing `elink` from the element's class list won't cause that click event to stop happening. is that where your confusion lies? otherwise... your question, and the code itself, is quite confusing.

Comment: no I don't think so, I'm really new to jquery so forgive me if this is totally wrong but my elements are a whole bunch of links that all start out with the class .elink but when I click one of these links it should change the class to .playing which it does but it also adds the class .paused which I only want it to do when the link with the class .playing is clicked.  So all I want to know is why is it when I click .elink it adds both .playing and .paused?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this?

```
        player();
        function player() {
          jQuery(".elink").click(function(e) {    
            jQuery(".playing").addClass("elink").removeClass("playing");
           jQuery(this).removeClass("elink").addClass("playing");
           return false;
          });
        }

        jQuery('body').on("click", ".playing", function(){
          jQuery(this).addClass("paused")
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me first explain you the difference between below two type of event binding.

**First one -** `jQuery(".elink").click(function(e) {`

This will find all the elements which has the class `.elink` and attaches the `click` event handler function to it. It is something like tightly coupled events (or remember the event is injected into each elements which has that class), That is its once attached it remains until the life of the element or until the `event` is manually removed. So given that, Now no matter what happens to the element like appending child, changing its class changing its position in HTML etc etc has no effect on the `event` that has been injected into it. Unless the event is removed as mentioned above.

**Second one -** `$('body').on("click", ".playing", function(){`

Here the `click` event is attached to the document level, But with one small difference. We give additional parameter saying on which elements should the following event handler function should work on. SO when ever there is a `click` event the jquery code will check if the `click` was on the specified element or its children, If yes it executes the function else not. Since it is attached into the document and not the specific elements the event will always work on any element which has the specified class **at the time of click**. These kind of event binding is called `event delegation` and are useful for handling events on dynamic elements.

Now with that knowledge, lets look into your code.

```
 jQuery(".elink").click(function(e) {    
   jQuery(".playing").addClass("elink").removeClass("playing");
   jQuery(this).removeClass("elink").addClass("playing");
   return false;
 });
```

You are strongly binding the event to the element with class `elink`, with in it you are changing its class to something else, But that doesnt stop it from running this function again on the next click. And according to current logic on every `click` you are adding the class `playing` no matter what.

> So I have some code where a class(elink) when clicked changes to a different class(playing), and then when .playing gets clicked it should change classes again to .pause,

To achieve this, you need to use the below logic.

```
player();
function player() {
  $(".elink").click(function(e) { // this is one time binding to element, so chnaging class names will have no effect on the execution of the event on further clicks
    var currentClass = $(this).attr('class');
    
    switch(currentClass){
     case 'elink': $(this).removeClass("elink").addClass("playing"); break;
     case 'playing': $(this).removeClass("playing").addClass("pause");break
     default?: break;
    }    
  });
}
```

Note I have removed the `event delegation` script, As we are handling the same element and the event always fires even if we change the class this is sufficient to handle the task.

Hope this helps.